# Как защитить сайт от перебора паролей?

Tags: php, javascript, веб-программирование, безопасность

Всем здарова, срочно нужна помощь. У меня реализована простая авторизация, в бд хранится e-mail, и хэш пароля. Пытаюсь сделать некоторую защиту, пока получается следующим образом: если была неудачная попытка авторизации с определённого ip, то я заношу этот ip в бд, и пока с этого ip не будет удачной попытки, вывожу капчу. Правильный ли это механизм, или есть варианты лучше? И да, что делать, если ip динамический? Заранее спасибо всем за ответ.

Comment: Даже если IP динамический. Он же не каждые 5 секунд меняется:)

Comment: на самом деле пароли часто перебирают не с одного ip а с множества, используя ботнеты или tor. так что если поток запросов действительно большой есть смысл поставить гугловскую капчу, которая сама пользователей определяет и показывать ее всегда. Или сделать доп. механизм защиты, например с помощью передачи из формы некого кода, который на страницу поставит JS-код (подборщики паролей скорее всего не будут выполнять JS)

Comment: Не надо проверять ip. 3 неудачных попытки, например, за последние 15 секунд - показывайте капчу для любого ip. Замучаются перебирать :)

Comment: А есть ли смысл помещать надобность капчи в сессию и в шаблоне выводить капчу, если $SESSION['captcha'], или злоумышленник каждый раз будет создавать новую сессию и это бесполезно?

Comment: @KamalAsfera, это бесполезно. Да еще и забить могут файлами сессий диск. Сессии вообще лучше использовать только на вошедших пользователях.

Comment: @Visman, значит только вариант с бд?

Comment: @KamalAsfera, можно попробовать файл. Хранить только время последних N неудачных попыток. Можно Memcache, быстро и нагрузки на базу/дисковую систему нет.

Comment: @Visman, понятно, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте так же защиту от [CSRF](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0)
А так вроде нормально, 10 попыток капча, еще 10 бан IP на 15 минут

Answer (score 0):

1. В первую очередь **CSRF**
2. Капча, надёжная, проверенная временем **Google Recapthca**
3. Подтверждение входа по почте (если заходит с нового **IP**)
4. (*опционально*) использование секретного **4-х** или **5-и** значного **пароля** . (*Если пользователь много раз ввёл неправильный пароль и затем успешно вошёл, можно предоставить заглушку в виде ввода секретного пароля.*)

По мне, так вариант с блокировкой входа если человек ввёл много раз неверный пароль, затрудняет использование приложения. Проще замораживать аккаунт до тех пор, пока не будет подтверждено лицо, которое пытается войти. Вариант с подтверждением по почте само собой.

Answer (score -3):

Капча + блокировка авторизации под этим юзером на несколько минут при неверных вводах несколько раз.

Ещё есть стремный метод: 1й раз верный пароль всегда не верный. Человек подумает что не правильно ввел и введет ещё раз. Бот же будет всегда подставлять новый пароль.

Comment: Блокировка авторизации юзера порождает возможность DoS-атаки: пишем скрипт, который бесконечно авторизуется с неправильным паролем, авторизация блокируется навечно и в результате даже настоящий юзер сайти не сможет. Достаём пачку айпишников, скармливаем скриптам список всех юзеров — в результате авторизоваться не сможет никто и никогда)

Comment: В противном случае, имея множество проксей - злоумышленник может получить полный доступ к аккаунту. Это лучше вариант?
Юзеру, при авторизации можно выводить сообщение, что аккаунт заблокирован на несколько минут по причине подбора пароля. Если вы владелец - свяжитесь с администрацией.

Comment: Нет, если пароль не из топ-10000 и длиннее хотя бы 6 символов, то это невозможно в разумные сроки. Если же пароль простой, то это проблемы пользователя, а не сайта :)

Comment: Если человек сам в пароле сомневается, то не будет он каждую версию по 2 раза вводить.